# My father died due to corona on eid ul fitr. Is there any hadis or anything related dying on eid ul fitr?

Tags: hadith, eid, martyr

Assalamualaikum everyone. My father died on last eid ul fitr due to novel covid19. Did allah said anything about those who dies on eid day?

Answer (score -1):

I’m not sure about, I read a link from a fatwa website and they said they couldn’t find any evidence specifically for eid but I believe he is comes under a martyr. May Allah grant your father the highest ranks in jannah.